# Read optimisation cassandra using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, datastax

I have a table with the following model:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (
                user_id bigint ,
                pseudo text,
                importance float,
                is_friend_following bigint,
                is_friend boolean,
                is_following boolean,
                PRIMARY KEY ((user_id), is_friend_following)
            );
```

I also have a table containing my seeds. Those (20) users are the starting point of my graph. So I select their ID and search in the table above to get their Followers and friends, and from there I build my graph (networkX).

```
def build_seed_graph(cls, name):
    obj = cls()
    obj.name = name
    query = "SELECT twitter_id FROM {0};"
    seeds = obj.session.execute(query.format(obj.seed_data_table))
    obj.graph.add_nodes_from(obj.seeds)
    for seed in seeds:
        query = "SELECT friend_follower_id, is_friend, is_follower FROM {0} WHERE user_id={1}"
        statement = SimpleStatement(query.format(obj.network_table, seed), fetch_size=1000)
        friend_ids = []
        follower_ids = []
        for row in obj.session.execute(statement):
            if row.friend_follower_id in obj.seeds:
                if row.is_friend:
                    friend_ids.append(row.friend_follower_id)
                if row.is_follower:
                    follower_ids.append(row.friend_follower_id)
        if friend_ids:
            for friend_id in friend_ids:
                obj.graph.add_edge(seed, friend_id)
        if follower_ids:
            for follower_id in follower_ids:
                obj.graph.add_edge(follower_id, seed)
    return obj
```

The problem is that the time it takes to build the graph is too long and I would like to optimize it.
I've got approximately 5 millions rows in  my table `'network_table'`.

I'm wondering if it would be faster for me if instead of doing a query with a where clauses to just do a single query on whole table? Will it fit in memory? Is that a good Idea? Are there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the real issue may not be the queries but rather the processing time.

> I'm wondering if it would be faster for me if instead of doing a query with a where clauses to just do a single query on whole table? Will it fit in memory? Is that a good Idea? Are there better way?

There should not be any problem with doing a single query on the whole table if you enable paging (https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html - using fetch_size). Cassandra will return up to the fetch_size and will fetch additional results as you read them from the result_set.

Please note that if you have many rows in the table that are non seed related then a full scan may be slower as you will receive rows that will not include a "seed"

Disclaimer - I am part of the team building ScyllaDB - a Cassandra compatible database.

ScyllaDB have published lately a blog on how to efficiently do a full scan in parallel http://www.scylladb.com/2017/02/13/efficient-full-table-scans-with-scylla-1-6/ which applies to Cassandra as well - if a full scan is relevant and you can build the graph in parallel than this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can get rid of the last 2 `if` statements, since you're going through data that you already have looped through once:

```
def build_seed_graph(cls, name):
    obj = cls()
    obj.name = name
    query = "SELECT twitter_id FROM {0};"
    seeds = obj.session.execute(query.format(obj.seed_data_table))
    obj.graph.add_nodes_from(obj.seeds)
    for seed in seeds:
        query = "SELECT friend_follower_id, is_friend, is_follower FROM {0} WHERE user_id={1}"
        statement = SimpleStatement(query.format(obj.network_table, seed), fetch_size=1000)
        for row in obj.session.execute(statement):
            if row.friend_follower_id in obj.seeds:
                if row.is_friend:
                    obj.graph.add_edge(seed, row.friend_follower_id)
                elif row.is_follower:
                    obj.graph.add_edge(row.friend_follower_id, seed)
    return obj
```

This also gets rid of many append operations on lists that you're not using, and should speed up this function.